# Please complile with -fPIE and link with -pie flag

Tags: unity-game-engine, tizen

I built a Unity Project for Tizen. Ran in an emulator in Tizen Studio, but I get this in the logs:

> ERROR / AUL_PAD ( 3370 : 3370 ) : launchpad_loader.c: main(713) > dlopen failed(/opt/usr/apps/com.example.nameapp.test/bin/nameapp: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory). Please complile with -fPIE and link with -pie flag

How do I fix it?

Comment: It seems Tizen emulator is not supported by unity yet. They have mentioned it here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/tizen-faq.html

Answer (score 0):

Executable file that can be your entry point of your app must be compile with `-fPIE` and `-pie` flag if you want to use it with `dlopen()` and `dlsym()`.

Basically, tizen system should start app with "launchpad" deamon.
"launchpad" deamon fork candidate process for future launching.
and this candidate process use `dlopen()` and `dlsym()` for open and start the executable of your application.

so your executable file must be build with `-fPIE` and `-pie` flag.

I don't know How to code is builded with Unity.
If you use Tizen Studio, you can check `-fPIE` is exist in `All options` in `project` -> `properties` -> `c/c++ build` -> `Settings` -> `C/C++ compiler` and also check `-pie` is exist in `All options` in `C/C++ linker`